# Ruby exception.message taking too much time

Tags: ruby, exception

I am seeing very interesting and catastrophic behavior with ruby, see the code below

```
class ExceptionTest

  def test
    @result = [0]*500000

    begin
      no_such_method
    rescue Exception => ex
      puts "before #{ex.class}"
      st = Time.now
      ex.message
      puts "after #{Time.now-st} #{ex.message}"
    end

  end
end

ExceptionTest.new.test
```

Ideally `ex.message` should not take any time to execute and hence Time taken should be in ms, but here is the output

```
before NameError
after 0.462443 undefined local variable or method `no_such_method' for #<ExceptionTest:0x007fc74a84e4f0>
```

If I assign `[0]*500000` to a local variable instead of instance variable e.g. `result = [0]*500000` it runs as expected

```
before NameError
after 2.8e-05 undefined local variable or method `no_such_method' for #<ExceptionTest:0x007ff59204e518>
```

**It looks like somehow `ex.message` is looping thru the instance variables, why it would do so, please enlighten me!**

I have tried it on ruby ruby-1.9.2-p290, ruby-1.9.1-p376, ruby 2.0.0 and whatever version the ruby on codepad.org is.

Edit: files a bug http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/8366

Comment: Did you actually reference the local variable so its creation wasn't optimized out entirely?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I did try to print first and last items at start and end of test method but still with local var it is fast, even if it was not, question remain how come ex.message is affected by all this

Comment: http://www.mikeperham.com/2012/03/03/the-perils-of-rescue-exception/

Comment: @ScottBartell what that has to do with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After digging into [the source](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_2_0_0/error.c#L1088-L1095), I found that `NameError#message` tries to call `inspect` on your object first, and if that string is too long, it calls `to_s` instead. It's expected that `inspect` would take a long time because it recursively inspects every instance variable. (See the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Object.html#method-i-inspect) for inspect.)

From error.c:

```
d = rb_protect(rb_inspect, obj, &state);
if (state)
  rb_set_errinfo(Qnil);
if (NIL_P(d) || RSTRING_LEN(d) > 65) {
  d = rb_any_to_s(obj);
}
desc = RSTRING_PTR(d);
```

You can boil down this test to see that it has nothing to do with exceptions after all:

```
class InspectTest
  def initialize
    @result = [0]*500000
  end

  def test
    puts "before"
    st = Time.now
    self.inspect
    puts "after #{Time.now-st}"
  end
end

InspectTest.new.test
#before
#after 0.162566

InspectTest.new.foo
# NoMethodError: undefined method `foo' for #<InspectTest:0x007fd7e317bf20>

e=InspectTest.new.tap {|e| e.instance_variable_set(:@result, 0) }
e.foo
# NoMethodError: undefined method `foo' for #<InspectTest:0x007fd7e3184580 @result=0>
e.test
#before
#after 1.5e-05
```

If you know your class will hold tons of data and might throw lots of exceptions, you could in theory override `#inspect`.

```
class InspectTest
  def inspect
    to_s
  end
end

InspectTest.new.test
#before
#after 1.0e-05
```

Comment: not understood the trick to use `InspectTest.new.foo` and `e.foo`. Can you bit explain these?

Comment: My only reason for calling `foo` was to trigger a `NoMethodError` and show what the output looks like. This shows that the class name is truncated when `inspect` is too long.

Comment: great thanks, still I consider it a bug as doing a inspect on object which can be huge will be always slow, what ruby was thinking, it is not practical to implement inspect more so when these are third party plugins, better is to override NameError#to_s

Comment: True, it's not efficient. However, I wouldn't expect `NameError` or `NoMethodError` to happen very much or at all in production. (These are the only types of exceptions affected.) I guess they tried to strike a balance between providing a useful but not overly-long error message. Overriding `NameError#to_s` would make the error message less useful for other classes that store a "normal" amount of data. `inspect` is the real problem because it outputs such a verbose representation of the object.

Comment: @davogones may be they should have a option 'inspect' in ex.message or a separate method ex.message_slow :) for now I only see overriding NameError#to_s as the only solution though I filed a bug http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/8366